# What is wrong with my python code ? Works fine for 40 and over , but not for below 40

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
hour = raw_input("Enter Hours")
rate = raw_input("Enter rate")  

if hour <= 40 :
# for less than 40 this part not executing    
    pay = float(hour)*float(rate) 
    print pay
else:   
    pay = (40*int(rate))+((float (hour)-40)*15)
    print pay
```

[image: output]

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, not an integer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing string to int. Use int casting:

```
hour=raw_input("Enter Hours")
rate=raw_input("Enter rate")   
if int(hour) <= 40:
# for less than 40 this part not executing    
    pay = float(hour)*float(rate) 
    print pay
else:   
    pay = (40*int(rate))+((float (hour)-40)*15)
    print pay
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful please set it as the correct answer with the checkmark icon.

Answer (score 2):

[`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) return string, so `if hour <= 40:` will do something like `if '10' <= 40`(lets say the input is `10`):

```
>>> foo = raw_input()
12
>>> type(foo)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

If you're using Python 3, it'll raise `TypeError`:

```
>>> foo = '10'
>>> foo <= 40
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()
>>>
```

But on Python 2.x, the output always is `False`:

```
>>> foo = '10'
>>> foo <= 40
False
>>>
```

Because the output always is `False`, so the `else` part also always run.

You can convert it to `int` or `float` when you reading it like this:

```
hour = float(raw_input("Enter Hours: "))
rate = float(raw_input("Enter rate: "))  

if hour <= 40 :
    # for less than 40 this part not executing    
    pay = hour*rate 
    print pay
else:   
    pay = (40*int(rate))+((hour-40)*15)
    print pay
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .